# Loading select box values from DB and array

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I have a code that will first load all the values into an array.
The values will be then given to select box. There will be totally 5 select boxes and it will load the same data.
I have tried my level best. And here is the code

```
    <?php
    $resultSet = array();
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_book_query))
    {
    $resultSet['Book_Code'][] = $result['Book_Code'];
    $resultSet['Book_Name'][] = $result['Book_Name'];
    }
    ?>

    <?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { ?>
    <select name="book_code_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="book_code">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="<?php  echo $resultSet['Book_Code'];?>"><?php  echo $resultSet['Book_Name'] ;?></option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is.

Show 5 select box with the same values (i.e the values wil be first loaded from DB and stored in array) and then load it inside the select box.

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 0):

This is not very handy way to operate with database results, seems as copy-pasted from an example with little understanding. Try it this way:

```
<?php
$resultSet = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_book_query))
{
    $resultSet[] = $result; //the code you had here is maybe working, but very unhandy
}
?>

<?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { ?>
  <select name="book_code_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="book_code">
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php foreach ($resultSet as $result) { //THIS is the important thing you missed
?>
    <option value="<?php  echo htmlspecialchars($result['Book_Code']);?>"><?php  echo htmlspecialchars($result['Book_Name']) ;?></option>
  <? } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, ALWAYS escape variables written to HTML using htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so as per the comment below, you can do:

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { ?>
<select name="book_code_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="book_code">
<option value=""></option>
<?php foreach($resultSet['Book_Code'] as $k=>$v){
   echo "<option value=".$v.">".$resultSet['Book_Name'][$k]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I believe he wants all 5 select boxes to contain the full list of options, not one per select.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$resultSet = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_book_query))
{
$resultSet[] = array(
                    'Book_Code' => $result['Book_Code'],
                    'Book_Name' => $result['Book_Name']
                    );
}
?>

<?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++): ?>
<select name="book_code_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="book_code">
<option value=""></option>
<?php foreach($resultSet as res):?>
    <option value="<?php  echo $res['Book_Code'];?>"><?php  echo $res['Book_Name'] ;?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>

</select>
<?php endfor;} ?>
```